# How to get a subpart of a regex

Tags: regex

I have this string:
`{0, plural, one[Sanglier] other[Sangliers]}`

I want the value inside the brackets of the key `one`, `Sanglier` in this case.

The following regex `one\[.*?\]` gives me `one[Sanglier]`

What regex could give me just `sanglier` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `one\[(.*?)\]` and then access the first capture which will be either `\1` or `$1` depending on which RegEx version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use positive lookahead and lookbehind

`(?<=one\[).*?(?=\])`

Comment: Good one, but not supported by all browsers !